# What is the difference between concrete RTN and abstract RTN?

Tags: assembly

I have been reading about RTN (Register Transfer Notation) and I have come upon abstract RTN. There is no explanation about the difference between concrete RTN and  abstract RTN.

Could anyone explain to me the difference between the two both in how you write the code and how it interacts with the machine?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't interact with the machine. It's purely a description of the Assembly language.

Abstract RTN is made to be Portable and so, doesn't have any specifics of the machine.
To the opposite, concrete RTN was made to work with the hardware of your machine. As such, every step in concrete RTN is equivalent to a processor cycle.